# Can you use the --verbose flag for individual Grunt tasks?

Tags: gruntjs, grunt-cli

Here's an example GruntFile for a "clean" task (using the [grunt-contrib-clean](https://github.com/gruntjs/grunt-contrib-clean) plugin):

```
clean: {
            dry: {
                src: ["build/css"],
                options: {
                    'no-write': true
                }
            }
        }
```

Running `grunt clean:dry` would output:

```
Running "clean:dry" (clean) task
>> 2 paths cleaned.

Done, without errors.
```

Using `grunt clean:dry -v`, gives me what I want:

```
Running "clean:dry" (clean) task
Not actually cleaning live/css...
Not actually cleaning live/js...
```

...but it also displays a bunch of configuration logs that have nothing to do with the current task. Can I use the --verbose flag (or something else) to show the full output of a task without having to scroll through all of the non-related config logs?

PS: My other plugins suffer from the same problem, displaying only a single line of output when their documentation indicates that I should expect more.

(Related questions: [Logging from grunt-contrib-jasmine](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14990335/logging-from-grunt-contrib-jasmine) and [How can I force JSHint running in grunt to always use the --verbose flag](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26144621/how-can-i-force-jshint-running-in-grunt-to-always-use-the-verbose-flag) do not answer this question).

Comment: Not as far as I know. Some individual plugins have an option to output more info, but if you use a CLI option it gets passed to all plugins, thus all of them would be "verbose".

Comment: Thanks for the quick feedback. I'm surprised that this can't be done, but the global --verbose will work for now.

Answer (score 0):

[There are some insights into this.](https://github.com/ericclemmons/grunt-verbosity/issues/4#issuecomment-23278456)

```
grunt.initConfig({
    verbosity: {
        default: {
            options: { mode: 'dot' }, // normal, oneline, dot, hidden
            tasks: ['groundskeeper', 'requirejs']
        }
    }
grunt.registerTask( '_start',  ['verbosity:default', 'projectInfo'] );
```